# add iPhone functionality to iPad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have been developing an iPad app.  I now want to make it work on the iPhone also.  What do I do in Xcode so it can work both ways?

(I am not concerned about adapting to the smaller screen -- that part I can figure out.  But how do I get it to start up on the iPhone?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project's build properties, change the target from "iPad" to "iPhone/iPad". Make sure you continue to target iOS 3.2, however, so that you don't break iPad support, and *test on both platforms*.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Now how do I switch back and forth between compiling for iPhone/iPad?

Comment: You compile for both simultaneously. It's a single "universal" binary. If you mean "how do I switch between the iPad and iPhone simulators", check the Target Settings drop-down menu at the top left of the Xcode project window.